# Why does Lucee's debug template error on a fresh installation?

Tags: lucee

I was a Railo user who just started setting up a new server.  As part of this migration I thought I would update to the newest version of Lucee as well.

The Lucee install went much smoother than I remember my last Railo install going and all sites worked immediately after setup.  However, when I set my IP address to show debugging information to I get the following error at the end of all pages on my sites:

```
 Message    template [[**My Webroot**]\Nightscape\WEB-INF\lucee\context\Component.cfc] must contain a component or an interface.
 Stacktrace The Error Occurred in
 C:\lucee\tomcat\lucee-server\context\context\admin\debug\Debug.cfc: line 1 
 1: <cfcomponent>
 2: 
 3: <cfset fields=array()>

 called from C:\lucee\tomcat\lucee-server\context\context\admin\debug\Modern.cfc: line 1
```

This occurs whether I set the debug template to classic or modern.  I haven't done anything on this server yet other than install Lucee, tweak some of the settings in the server admin, and setup my sites in IIS.  I did try to navigate to [**My Webroot**]\Nightscape\WEB-INF\lucee\context\Component.cfc and found that it is just a blank file; is it supposed to have content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that some other sites were working once they were setup.  Upon comparison, the other sites had the following content in \WEB-INF\lucee\context\Component.cfc

```
 <cfcomponent displayname="Component" hint="This is the Base Component"></cfcomponent>
```

A similar problem happened with other sites leading to a variety of errors, but they all traced back to zero length files created by Lucee that I just had to copy from other sites.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Would you be so kind as to submit a bug report so that this can be looked into and corrected? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Jordan Sorry, I did try.  I couldn't figure out how, though.  I finally found a link to the "Issue Tracker", which took me to a dashboard explaining how I could help fix issues and become a developer for the Lucee engine.  Nothing on the page said anything about submitting a bug report.  If you can point me to the right place I will try again.